# Python xlrd parse Excel xlsx to csv with date conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, xlrd

I am trying to parse an Excel.xlsx file to a csv file. Here is the Excel file:

```
Date         Person 1     Person 2  
02/03/2015   Bob          James A       
03/03/2015   Billy        Nic       
04/03/2015   Sally        Mark      
05/03/2015   Alan         James A       
06/03/2015  James W       James A
```

My Python script:

```
import xlrd
import csv

book = xlrd.open_workbook('rota.xlsx')

sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

csvfile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
  wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))

csvfile.close()
```

however it outputs the dates like this:

```
Date,Person1,Person2
41884,Bob,James B
41885,Billy,Nic
41886,Sally,Mark
41887,Alan,James A
41888,James W,James A
```

I am aware of the xldate_as_tuple function or something like this to convert the output to meaningful values but I can't figure out how to use it.
Any help I would be most grateful.

Comment: You don't appear to have *tried* to use `xldate_as_tuple` - why not?

Comment: I don't know where to put it into my code quite simply!

Comment: Learning curve for me this is...

Comment: Well, where is the date? Have you looked at `sheet.row_values(rownum)`? Do you know what it is, and how to access the individual values in it? Have you followed a decent Python tutorial?

Comment: The date is in column A (or [0] I suppose as xlrd would refer to it?)
I have had great difficulty finding a "decent" tutorial on xlrd...

Comment: This isn't really an `xlrd` problem! You have used `xlrd` successfully to get you a sequence of the objects in that row, now you just need to process them.

Comment: Aha! Right so now I have to process the parsed data.
This presumably involves iterating through the columns or rows or cells (?) and then processing them accordingly?

Comment: Now you're getting somewhere!

Comment: Right! I shall do some research then. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution:

```
import xlrd
import csv
from datetime import datetime


book = xlrd.open_workbook('rota.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
csvfile = open('output5.csv', 'wb')

wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(0))

for rownum in range(1,sheet.nrows):
  year, month, day, hour, minute, sec = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(sheet.row_values(rownum)[0]), book.datemode)
  py_date = datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)
  wr.writerow([py_date] + sheet.row_values(rownum)[1:])

csvfile.close()
```

Output:

```
"Date      "," Person 1","Person 2"
"2015-02-03 00:00:00"," Bob     ","James A "
"2015-03-03 00:00:00"," Billy   ","Nic     "
"2015-04-03 00:00:00"," Sally   ","Mark    "
"2015-05-03 00:00:00"," Alan    ","James A "
"2015-06-03 00:00:00","James W  ","James A "
```

Version2:

Code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import xlrd
import csv
from datetime import datetime

book = xlrd.open_workbook('rota.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
csvfile = open('output5.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    date = sheet.row_values(rownum)[0]
    if isinstance( date, float) or isinstance( date, int ):
        year, month, day, hour, minute, sec = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date, book.datemode)
        py_date = "%02d/%02d/%04d" % (month, day,year)
        wr.writerow([py_date] + sheet.row_values(rownum)[1:])
    else:
        wr.writerow(sheet.row_values(rownum))
csvfile.close()
```

Output:

```
"Date      "," Person 1","Person 2"
"02/03/2015"," Bob     ","James A "
"03/03/2015"," Billy   ","Nic     "
"04/03/2015"," Sally   ","Mark    "
"05/03/2015"," Alan    ","James A "
"06/03/2015","James W  ","James A "
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me an error:
Traceback(most recent call last):
 File "pythonscript.py", line 14, in <module>
  year, month, day, hour, minute, sec = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(int(sheet.row_values(rownum)[0]), book.datemode)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Any ideas as to how to deal with this?

Comment: That means some of the values you have are not dates. I have posted version 2, it should work.

Comment: I thank you very much for your help - that is perfect. the csv file looks good, I changed quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL to delimiter=',' to get the output I wanted. Excellent! I want to process the csv file now to display the name of the person who is on the same line as the current date. Is this the right way to do it or should I really import the Excel data to an array instead of a csv file? Maybe I should post a new question.
Thank you so much for your help Stanislav!!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. I assume this could work. Since it is a different problem posting a new question would be nice.

Comment: I have that rota (Excel rota.xlsx) that someone else makes. The rota tells me who is responsible for a job on a given day (Person 1 col in rota), I want to take the data from the rota.xlsx, and email the person in Person 1 col to remind them that it's their day to do the job. So I parse the rota.xlsx, then find person 1 who is listed at the current date, and then email them to remind them. I want to do it all in one script...I will think about how to post this as a proper question maybe?